# Open .c File in an iOS App.(How to handle .c files in IOS app)

Tags: ios, objective-c

My iOS app should be able to open  `.c` files. It is basically a C program Reader. I added the `.c` files to the Bundle. But xcode is compiling it and giving error "Conio.h not found". I tried reading the file using WEBVIEW but showing error. Here is my code.

```
NSString *nameOfFile= @"TestC";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nameOfFile ofType:@"c"];

if (path) {
    NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
else
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"File not found" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show] ;
}
```

Can anyone please Help. Thank You

Comment: You need to create the header files. You should have and .c files, with several functions, and some of them you want to fire out. Well this functions than you want to fire out of the c implementation (In your objective-C code) must be in the header files. If you need I can put and example as answer.

Comment: @Onik I have alot of files which are added dynamically. So keeping track of all the functions used is tricky. It will be helpfull if you post that example as answer. Will try it

Comment: Sorry, do you have a C program with several files ?, But you don't have header in order to include one file in others. I can understand.

Comment: Onik that problem got solved. But now webview cant handle .c files. I am stuck there.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.c` file from all build targets (you can see the targets it's associated with in the righthand pane within Xcode) and just ensure it's configured within the build phase to be copied into the app bundle.

Comment: I am new to XCODE. Can you please elaborate more about your solution. I am not getting how to remove file from build target.

Comment: @VinayakParmar With the source file loaded (single click) you should find a *Target Membership* list of checkboxes in the righthand pane.  Deselect all targets.

Comment: Yea that worked.Not showing error. But this code is now not detecting .c files. Am I using the wrong way to open file. Like it works if it is a txt file.But for .c not working.

Comment: @VinayakParmar First you need to ensure it's being copied into the app bundle via the build phase. The way you are loading it looks fine, however I'm not sure how a `UIWebView` will handle a `.c` file being loaded into it.  Add some logging so you can see what is happening.

Comment: Yea. The web view cannot handle .c files.Is there any way known to you to handle .c files

Comment: @VinayakParmar Start a new question about how to display the `.c` file.  As far as this question is concerned, I believe I have answered it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a litle C program to a Xcode (Objective - C) project.

I'm going to add this to C files:

TestingC.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myMainCFunction();
```

TestingC.c:

```
#include "TestingC.h"

int myMainCFunction()
{
printf("Hello world\n");

return 0;
}
```

In my ViewController I add:

```
#import "TestingC.h"
```

And in the viewDidLoad, I ´m going to call the C program:

```
 myMainCFunction();
```

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question.

Comment: @Onik. Like we have PDF reader. I am making a C program reader. So now how to open those C programs.Web view cant open it